# using a javascript variable to refer to an element with id containing the variable

Tags: javascript, html

HTML
In my html I have an element with id ="check1"

```
<span id="check1"></span>
```

JAVASCRPIT
I have a variable a='1', which is coming from somewhere else.
Now, I want the inner HTML of span element to be "correct" with the help of reference to its id, and using 'a'.

```
var a = 1;
$.(#**checka**).innerHTML="correct"
```

How to write the id ??

Comment: `document.getElementById("check" + a).innerHTML = "correct";` if using jquery: `$("#check" + a).html("correct");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first notice that `innerHTML()` is `javascript` and the `jquery` function is `html()`
and always remember that you can use concatenation everywhere.
with that said:

```
$('#check' + a).html('correct');
```

Answer (score 2):

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("check" + a).innerHTML = "correct";
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("#check" + a).html("correct");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#check' + a).html('correct');
```

or

```
$('#check' + a)[0].innerHTML = ('correct');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('check' + a).innerHTML = ('correct');
```